# sql update statement doesn't work

Tags: php, sql

I have to increment a field in my DB each time I execute this statement:

```
$sql="UPDATE `product` SET buyCount = buyCount+1 WHERE id=".$productID;
```

But it doesn't work. Any help ?

Comment: After the above statement add 'echo $sql;' and look at the result. It will let you know if your query is well-formed.

Comment: Do you actually check the result of the query?  It may be failing, because $productID does not have a valid value when the query is run.  See http://www.flingbits.com/article/view/my-script-with-mysql-calls-doesn-t-work-why-1 and make sure you are doing what that article shows.  However, it also could be what Gordon provided as an answer.  You need to check both situations.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess would be that BuyCount is initialized to NULL and not 0.  Try:

```
set BuyCount = coalesce(BuyCount, 0) + 1
```

Alternatively, your where clause is failing.  You might try setting a value in another column to see if it is working.

Comment: Agreed, this is most likely.  See:  http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/91-Mysql-Update-Null-+-1-is-Null!.html

Answer (score -1):

Move your closing " to the end of the query and enclose the variable in single quotes.

```
$sql="UPDATE product SET buyCount = buyCount+1 WHERE id='$productID'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$sql="UPDATE product SET buyCount = buyCount+1 WHERE id= $productID";
```